# Keras callback error due to folders permission

Tags: python, linux, keras, callback, directory-permissions

I have a keras model that has a `ModelCheckpoint` callback.

when I set the path in the callback to `tmp` folder, it works perfectly, but when I set it to another folder that called `kaggle` I get an error.

The error is quite long, and this is the last part of it:

```
    21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7804 - acc: 0.50482020-04-28 17:36:20.771950: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: indices[5,12] = 11086 is not in [0, 11086)
         [[{{node embedding/embedding_lookup}}]]
2020-04-28 17:36:20.778527: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: indices[5,12] = 11086 is not in [0, 11086)
         [[{{node embedding/embedding_lookup}}]]
         [[dense_1_target/_2]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/DIRECTORY2/train.py", line 76, in <module>
    Train(args)
  File "/DIRECTORY2/train.py", line 28, in __init__
    Train.train(params.read(configs))
  File "/DIRECTORY2/train.py", line 69, in train
    verbose = 1)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1433, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 264, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1175, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3443, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 561, in __call__
    return self._call_flat(args)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 660, in _call_flat
    outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 434, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/DIRECTORY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[5,12] = 11086 is not in [0, 11086)
         [[{{node embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_3082]
```

I printed the permission for both folders and it looks that they have the same permission!
[image]

**Edited (1):**

The directory that caused the error was transfered to my linux user using WinSCP program from another windows machine, while the other one (`tmp`) was created by locally in linux.

**Edited (2):**

I deleted the directory that caused the error and created the same one locally and the error disapeared!. I'm quite sure that the error is due to directories permissions but I don't know what was the source.

Comment: Your callback just save the model or use the folder data? By the error log it's not a permission issue, but a graph shape issue. Seems you're trying to feed a model or do some math using TF but the shape of your data is wrong

Comment: @AugustoMaillo, just save the model. But it works with the `tmp` folder! I don't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure the it works always with tmp folder? Everywhere i search for this error says that's a shape problem. Somewhere in your code you do "indices[5,12] = 11086" ?

Comment: @AugustoMaillo , totally sure. Maybe this error happen after a permission issue.

Comment: Try to use another folder, maybe one inside tmp and check if it works. The checkpointing callback that you're using is keras ModelCheckpoint?

Comment: Please post the complete traceback, I do not see a permissions error in the current traceback.

Comment: @AugustoMaillo yes, please see the question, I edited it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro , I added it.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that it's a permission error? From what I see, it's due to the embedding layer input size. Probably you have not set it properly and have not included the padding (or OOV token) in the input size. Increase the embedding layer input dimension by one, i.e. `tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, ...)`.

Comment: @today, by changing the path in `ModelCheckpoint`. I already do it.

Comment: As I mentioned, nothing in the traceback you have posted suggest that there is a directory permission error. Rather, it clearly says that it's an embedding lookup error.